# Cost function $C(x) = 8x+150$, and it has gone up by $19\%$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Cost function $C(x) = 8x+150$, and it has gone up by $19\%$

What is the new cost function, define as $N(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $\;Y\;$ is any quantity, if it goes *up* by $\;t\;$% then the new quantity is

$$Y\left(1+\frac t{100}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$N(x)=1.19\cdot C(x)$$